# Convert LPSTR to CString

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, c-strings

I'm on an old VS2010 project using CString which I'm really not well acquainted with.
I need to retrieve the %TEMP% path so I thought about using GetTempPath() function.

The issue is that I can't make it back to CString once I get my result.

I tried the following :

```
LPSTR Path = new CHAR(MAX_PATH);
GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH-1, Path);
this->m_FolderPath = (CString)Path;
```

While it seems functionnal in debug, it crashes in release. So I would assume this is not how I'm supposed to do it.

Thank you for any idea

Comment: I am not sure about `CString` casting operator. But it has a constructor that accepts a character pointer. So you can try to use `this->m_FolderPath = CString(Path);`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work unfortunately
Or maybe the crash is somewhere else in the code :think:

Comment: how you think - what `new CHAR(MAX_PATH)` is doing ?

Comment: omg it was `new CHAR[MAX_PATH]`
I copy pasted someone on another post without looking & didn't notice
Thank you

Comment: There's almost never a reason to call operator `new` in C++. The code should be using `std::vector<CHAR>`. Besides, if you are using `CHAR` and call the ANSI version of an API (`GetTempPathA`), then the compatible MFC string type is `CStringA`. `CString` is compatible with `TCHAR`s, which no one should be using. As a precautionary measure you can define the preprocessor symbol `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` to have the compiler catch accidental encoding conversions.

Comment: With a small character array like that (particularly one that is going to be discarded immediately after the operation in question) I would say just put it on the stack: "char path[MAX_PATH];" don't worry about either new or std::array.

Comment: `CHAR Path[MAX_PATH] = {}; GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH, Path); this->m_FolderPath = Path;`